# "Permission denied" when linker tries to open output executable?

Tags: c++, opengl, ld, glut, freeglut

I was trying to add texture in my freeglut opengl code:

```cpp
#include <GL/glut.h>
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

GLuint texture;

void loadTexture(const char* filename) {
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filename, &width, &height, &nrChannels, STBI_rgb_alpha);
    if (!data) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load texture: %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    stbi_image_free(data);
}

void frontscreen(){
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f( 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f( 1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f(-1.0f,  1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void renderBitmapString(float x, float y, void *font, const char *string) {
    const char *c;
    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    for (c = string; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(font, *c);
    }
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    frontscreen();
    renderBitmapString(-0.5, -0.9, GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "Press Enter");

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch(key) {
        case 27: // Escape key
            glutDestroyWindow(glutGetWindow()); // Exit the main loop
            break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutGameModeString("1920x1080:32@60");
    glutEnterGameMode();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    loadTexture("frontscreen.jpg");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glutMainLoop(); // This will run until you press the Escape key

    return 0;
}
```

...but this error popup every time:

```
gcc -c -o example.o sphere.cpp   && g++ -o example.exe example.o  -lfreeglut -lopengl32 -lglu32 -Wl,--subsystem,windows   && example.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file example.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: Is the exe running?

Comment: Delete example.exe before compiling a new one. This doesn't fix the issue, but is a workaround while you make changes.

Comment: Here are a few reasons I can think of: 1) The executable may still be running / perhaps you have a debug session open? 2) Your antivirus may be the problem, 3) You may have tried to get around a problem in the past and ran your IDE as the administrator breaking your permissions now.